# SQLite: How can I copy data from a column in table 1 and paste the data on a column of table 2 according to IDs of the data in specific rows?

Tags: sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite

In TABLE 1 (LEFT SIDED), I have lists of words in a column(WordEng) and each of them have unique IDs listed parallel in another column(WordEngID).

[image]
In TABLE 2 (RIGHT SIDED), I have lists of word IDs, which is nothing but unique IDs of words in TABLE 1. I want to copy words from TABLE 1  into a column in TABLE 2 according to its unique IDs.  In Table 1 no words have same IDs and in Table 2 the same IDs are in different rows.

For example,

there is a word "cut" with ID "1807" in Table 1 and I want to copy and paste it in the  column "words" in Table 2 which have IDs "1807"(five in this case).

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @strawberry Kindly help me with this. I'm new to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE Table2
SET words = (SELECT t1.WrdEng FROM Table1 t1 WHERE t1.WrdEngId = Table2.WrdEngId)
WHERE words IS NULL
```

If you want all the values of `words` updated, even if they are not `null`, then remove the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: The query runs for two minutes and shows 20207 rows affected but no changes are made in any of the columns

Comment: I really need help in this

Comment: @TheAccidentalMedico post sample data in text tabular format and not images or better create a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27 so I can test the query.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=18e49ac461642c8b5e182561f06af5a0

Comment: @TheAccidentalMedico your fiddle does not contain any sample data, so I can't test the query.

Comment: @TheAccidentalMedico I had  a typo: `t1.WrdEng` instead of `t1.WrdEngId`. try my edited code.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=53f6dad7e7632cc85840de581e47b4a5

Comment: I can't thank you enough brother. You saved my 2 months of time. I copy pasted half of the database and it took me more than a month . thank you so much